# .htaccess ignores rewrite cond on SymLinks

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I'm trying to get my rewrite module to ignore SymLinks because I need to access my files and host a website on the same url.

Here is my file list:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 17 14:43 css
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   16 Jun 17 14:26 downloads -> /home/downloads/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 17 14:44 error
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 17 14:44 fonts
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 17 14:44 images
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 17 14:44 includes
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1864 Jun 17 14:46 index.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jun 17 14:44 js
```

And here is my .htaccess content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-h
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-L
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-H
(I tried all of them)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z/]+)?$    index.php?vars=$1 [NC,L]
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l` works but you also need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` since you are creating a link of a directory.

Comment: Do you really believe `Still not working` type of comments will help you solve your problem?

Comment: Do you really think that if I had not tried anything I would ask here ?